# Is there a validation suite for multithreaded memory allocators?

Tags: c++, multithreading, testing, memory-management

I will soon be distributing a C++ concurrency framework that includes 64-bit multithreaded memory allocation services with particular advantages.  Although it has been tested and used for years (Windows7), and seemingly flawless, I really want validation from an independent source, to give my users the same confidence in using these services that I have.  And if I am really lucky and fortunate, such testing will reveal further defects (to resolve).  Obviously, we can already test this material quilte effectively.  But a publicly recognized validation suite is what I am ask about here.

Answer (score 0):

[TCMalloc](http://goog-perftools.sourceforge.net/doc/tcmalloc.html) contains a unit test program t-test1.c which they say

> forks a number of threads and performs a series of allocations and deallocations in each thread; the threads do not communicate other than by synchronization in the memory allocator.

The emphasis seems to be performance testing (number of random allocations and deallocations per second as a function of the number of concurrent threads).

I think `forks a number of threads` is poor wording, perhaps `creates a number of threads` would be better, otherwise one might get the impression they are forking new processes and the whole purpose is to have multiple threads sharing the same heap in the same virtual address space.

Comment: Thank you for that option, though it is unclear how much we can glean from one opaque black box evaluating another.  Perhaps I am asking for too much, and should simply provide my allocator in a form easy for others to evaluate.